# Update query giving timeout from C# but working fast from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Have an `update` statement as below:

```cs
using (SqlCommand sql_upd = new SqlCommand(@"update table1 set f_name=@file_name,f_date=getdate() 
    where f_id=@c_no", sql_con))
{
    sql_upd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_name", "file_n");
    sql_upd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_no", m_rdr["f_id"].ToString());
    sql_upd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This is causing a timeout expired error from C#. But the same query is working fine from SQL Server:

> Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Table script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1]
( 
    [f_id] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,  
    [f_name] [varchar](75) NULL,    
    [f_date] [datetime] NULL)  

    CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([f_id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: How long does it take from ssms ?

Comment: Please check `connection string` of your app, and being sure it is accessible.

Comment: @MichaelRandall 0 seconds in SSMS

Comment: @HassanMonjezi it is accessible since my select statements and all are working

Comment: I think you question need more info, so others can help. Please share exact error you are getting. I think it's not about `timeout` actually.

Comment: What type is field f_id in database int or char?
If it is int please try to cast m_rdr["f_id"] to int.

Comment: @Anve its varchar

Comment: @Sachu Ok, did you open connection to execute command?

Comment: @Anve yes it is open..I am able to execute the select statement just before this update

Comment: @Sachu Could you edit your question and add script for creating table1? So I can check at my machine.

Comment: @anve edited with table script

Comment: @Sachu I tried on my machine and this command passed without any problems.

Comment: Could you try same command with ExecuteScalar?

Comment: What happens when you [stop using `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)?

Comment: @Anve tried executescalar..same issue..

Comment: @GSerg same issue even after addwithvalue

Comment: Can you wrap ExecuteNonQuery in try catch block.